# How to limit number of values for field collection returned in a vew

Tags: views

I have a content type with a field collection item. The field collection includes an image field and a text field. Unlimited items can be added.

I have a view that is using only the image field. I want to show only the first image in the view. However there is no "multiple values"settings available when adding this field.

I have am able to use a conditional to only render the first image, however the view still creates a blank space for each additional image in the node. How can I get the view to only show the first image.

The code I have tried is below:

```
if ($data->field_data_field_add_images_delta == 0)  
 {
 print '<a href="/rooms-houses/' . $row->title . '/' . $row->nid . '/' . $row->uid . '">  ' . render($data->field_field_collection_upload_image) . ' </a>';
  }
```

Comment: What type of view did you create? a Content view or a Field collection view?

Comment: Content view. I did this because I am also including other content types in the view. If I were only using the content type that included the field collection, I could use a contextual filter with the image delta defaulting to 0. However, if I do that, the other content will not be displayed.

Comment: Is the field collection field a multivalued field?

Comment: Yes it is multivalued.

Comment: Then in the content view you should be able to see two view fields (one with delta and without) add the without delta to the views field then you should be able to find the multivalued settings.

Comment: This helped me figure it out. While I didn't see two fields, I think this was because I was only able to access the image field of the field collection after I added a relationship to this field. When I checked the settings for this relationship, I saw I could choose how many delta's to show. Once I selected 1 it worked perfectly.